# XCode 4 Debug Device Issue

Tags: ios4

I am running XCode 4 GM.  My application compiles and runs beautifully in the iPad simulator but fails to link when I choose to debug on the Device.
My device is an iPad with 4.2.1 ... and has the provisioning profile already installed.
Debugging worked fine on the iPad yesterday using XCode 3.2.

We opened the XCode 3.2 project in XCode 4 and got right to work.  The provisioning profile was already on the device.

The exact link error is as follows:

```
ld: in /Users/suki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LeapLanguage-btybcercrjdgyiawupkkhougaswm/Build/Intermediates/LeapLanguage.build/Debug-iphoneos/LeapLanguage.build/Objects-normal/armv7/unzip.o, in section __TEXT,__text reloc 22: R_ABS reloc but no absolute symbol at target address
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Can anyone help shed some light on this?
We are baffled ...

Comment: you should take this question to devforums.apple.com . you signed a NDA with apple, and xcode 4 is still covered by it.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar problem. I changed compiler to GCC 4.2 and this change solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/374029

@ fluchtpunkt is right. This doesn't belong on StackOverflow because it deals with [REDACTED] 4.